# PHP. Вывести массив после авторизации и редиректа

Tags: php, post, redirect

Делаю авторизацию на сайте. Когда пользователь вводит данные, они отправляются на сервер, обрабатываются и возвращают сообщение. Но проблема состоит в том, что, после того как пользователь нажимает кнопку "Авторизация", у меня происходит двойной редирект(кажется так он называется), то есть, первый раз редирект происходить после того как пользователь отправляет данные, а второй раз, это делает написана мною функция. Сейчас покажу как у меня это все дело работает:

**Функция в файле model.php**

```
function authorization(){
    $link = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) 
            or die(mysqli_error($link));``

    $responseArray =[];
    $access = true;
    $login = clear($_POST['login']);
    $password = clear($_POST['password']);
    $login_hash = md5(md5(time()+time()*rand(2,10)));

    if(empty($login)) 
        $responseArray['error']['login']='Логін не може бути пустим';

    if(empty($password)) 
        $responseArray['error']['password']='Пароль не може бути пустим';


    if($responseArray['error']) $access = false;

    if($access) {
        $select_query = "SELECT id, user, password, login_hash, user_ip 
                         FROM user_credentials 
                         WHERE user='$login'  
                         AND activated=1";

        $select_result = mysqli_query($link, $select_query) 
                         or die(mysqli_error($link));

        if (mysqli_num_rows($select_result) > 0) {
            $select_arr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_result);
            $password_correct = $select_arr['password'];

            if (!password_verify($password, $password_correct)) {
                $responseArray['error']['denied']='Хибний логін або пароль';
                $_SESSION['auth']['login']=$login;

            } else {

                $query_insert="UPDATE user_credentials 
                               SET login_hash='$login_hash' 
                               WHERE user_credentials.user='$login'";

                mysqli_query($link, $query_insert) or die(mysqli_error($link));

                setcookie('auth',$login_hash, time()+3600*2, '/admin/');
                setcookie('login', md5($login), time()+3600*2, '/admin/');

                $responseArray['success']['auth']='Вітаємо у системі';
            }

        } else {
            $responseArray['error']['denied'] = 'Такого користувача неіснує';
            $_SESSION['auth']['login']=$login;
        }
    }
return $responseArray;
}
```

После этого данные отправляются на сервер, и должен возвратится `$responseArray` 
с нужным сообщением.

Но в файле `controller.php`, там где я вызываю ф-цию в нужный момент, я написал следующее :

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'  && isset($_POST['authorization'])){
       $responseArray = authorization();
       redirect();
    }
```

`redirect();` - это у меня отдельная ф-ция, которая перегружает страницу. Это я делаю для того чтобы предотвратить повторную отправку формы в случае если пользователь перегрузит страницу. 
Вот сама ф-ция:

```
function redirect(){
    $redirect=isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : VIEW;
    header("Location: $redirect");
    exit;
}
```

Вывод сообщений у меня происходит в файле `authorization.php`

**Что мне нужно?** 
После того, как пользователь нажмет кнопку авторизации, чтобы выводились сообщения из массива `responseArray` после вот этого `redirect();`. Без него, все работает отлично, выводится. Но как только я делаю редирект, массив пропадает. Посоветуйте как мне решить этот вопрос. Спасибо.

Comment: складывайте массив куда-нить в сессию

Answer (score 0):

Я когда то делал вывод сообщений через сессию, как то так:

```
$_SESSION['message']['error']='Неверный логин или пароль';
```

Но мне сказали что вывод подобного через сессию это плохая идея, и назвали гавнокодом). И вот теперь пытаюсь делать по другому, а как правильно, не особо понимаю

Comment: Не помню точно, толи в CodeIgniter, толи в Yii(1), специально для этого была реализована подобная функция, как раз через сессии. Лично мне кажется, это норм. Но нужно быть уверенным, что сессия уже стартовала через `session_start()`.

Comment: в codeigniter Flashdata

Comment: Добавлю, что при реализации подобной функции, нужно будет после получения информации очищать поле (как в том же CI), чтобы не выдавать сообщения постоянно. Т.е. вносим данные перед редиректом `...setFlashData('messageForUser', $message)`, а при выводе этого сообщения через `...getFlashData('messageForUser')` - в методе/функции должна происходить автоматическая очистка поля по ключу `'messageForUser'`

Comment: Зачем писать ошибки в сессию? Когда нужно чтобы сервер сразу отвечал на запрос, а не понять куда записывал, а только потом выводил. Плохой пример.

Comment: Можно делать через сессию, иногда даже нужно, чтоб не передавать никаких параметров и не придумывать ничего прочего...просто нужно грамотно написать пару set и get методов...@A1essandro выше описал примерно как именно

Answer (score 0):

Если 301 редирект для `GET` - данные в конечный скрипт придут: клиент (браузер) проследует редиректу, может нескольким, и если последний вернет 2xx - будут использованы эти данные.

С `POST` запросом ситуация другая: если возвращается 301, клиент идет по новому адресу, но уже c `GET`. Чтобы клиент снова кинул постом, возвращайте при редиректе 307.

Answer (score -1):

Передавайте массив через сессию между скриптами.
Хотя, лучше избегать принудительных редиректов страниц: это очень раздражает пользователя.

Для предотвращения повторной отправки данных можно сделать следующее:

1. генерируем случайное число и запоминаем его в сессию
2. добавляем на форму скрытое поле с этим случайным числом
3. в обработчике проверяем, совпадает ли число из сессии с тем, что
   передали из формы. Если да, то страница не перезагружалась и можно
   работать. Если нет, то пользователь обновлял страницу и нам повторно
   принимать данные не нужно